# linux grep command with file name that exist

Tags: linux, grep

I am new to Linux. When I typed `grep filename` and pressed <kbd>enter</kbd>, it showed a blank line with cursor and I had to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to exit. Shouldn't it be showing me some kind of error that command is not complete? In short, what is happening after I type `grep filename` and pressed <kbd>enter</kbd>.

[Here is my commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ostGl.jpg)

Comment: Please replace image by text.

Comment: At the very least read a shell tutorial before trying to write shell scripts. Learning by trial and error would be a long, painful process for you (and for us :-) ). I recommend the book Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson.

Comment: i need answer not suggestion & learning from training videos sometimes u do mistakes or miss something what teacher is teaching and when not able to understand its good to ask question. Plus i my self and others too like to follow one teacher so they dont get confuse. plz never suggest book to some one unless he ask specificely or if u r book sales person then go ahead continue.  any ways thanks for worst answer ever

Comment: btw Shell scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson is for little bit advanced people i am just beginner and today is my 14th day with Linux still learning & long way to go. i am really really disappointed by your miss guided reply. i just read one paragraph from your mention book and understood this is not my level yet. so again really really disappointed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `grep test1`, then `test1` is not the filename but the pattern you are searching for and your input file is `stdin`. Therefore your console input will be your 'input file'. You can see that when you input a line which contains the string "test1" in which case the pattern matches and it is printed out immediately again on the console.

See [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) for the man page of it

> grep searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are
>   named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name)

Comment: thanks DAXaholic. u cleared what i missed in lecture. thanks and v v thanks for not suggesting some book and trying to explain. actually in books & man pages every thing is explained but its ok if me or someone else dosent understand it happen. plz i request admin of this great helpfull webiste to block book salespersons like Ed Morton. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can run `grep` in different ways.

What you probably wanted to de was to run `grep` like this:

```
$ grep pattern file
```

This will return all lines in `file` that contains `pattern`.

If you run `grep` like this:

```
$ grep pattern
```

The `grep` utility will read from *standard input* (the keyboard in this case), and will echo every line that you type back at you that matches the pattern.

For example:

```
$ grep 'images'
Cut word lines
Cut music lines
Smash the control images
Smash the control images
Smash the control machine
```

The second line saying "Smash the control images" is printed by `grep` as soon as I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing it the first time.

Notice that `grep` *assumes* that the first thing it gets (apart from command line options) is a pattern. It doesn't matter if I have a file called `images` in my example.